# Is it possible to bracket with flash only around a manual setting on Nikon D7000+SB700?

Tags: nikon-d7000, off-camera-flash, bracketing, sb-700

I have a Nikon D7000 and a SB-700 flash and am trying to set up the following:

- Manual mode (F11, 1/250)
- Manual flash (1/64)
- Bracketing with flash only +- 1 stop, i.e. one picture at flash power 1/64, one at 1/32 and one at 1/128.

I have the flash set up on the camera with a TTL cable (so should be equivalent to having it attached directly to the camera). I can set manual flash power easy enough on the flash itself, and I can set the D7000 to bracket with flash only in TTL mode, but have not found a way of bracketing around a specific flash power.

Is this possible and if so how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "YES" - it is possible. However I have not SB-700 and TTL-cord but I really think that it is meaningless.

I just did the following:

- Camera in **M**
- Flash is in **TTL/BL/FP** mode
- Flash ctrl for built-in flash (e3 menu setting) is in **Manual 1/50** of full power
- Auto bracketing set (e5 menu setting) in **Flash only** mode
- Bkt button in **3F, +/-1.0**

And the 3 shots I've got was with the same exposure settings (ISO, shutter speed and aperture) and 3 different flash powers (-1, 0 and 1 stops).

Camera is Nikon D7000, flash is Nikon SB-900 mounted on a camera.

You can keep your camera e3 setting in TTL mode. In this case if you need to adjust your flash power manually you will need to adjust its power by exposure compensation of your camera (I tried it myself - the flash power is really going up or down depending on your EC setting). However you have to keep in mind that if your subject is changing (distance, subject reflectivity or even, probably the amount of ambient light) your camera will change the flash power as well. I think it's a good thing generally, but if you would like to have a full control over the flash power - put e3 menu setting in manual.